# Docker IPv6 multiple services on same port in different containers

Tags: docker, ipv6

I am trying to pass through ports to docker containers, where multiple containers have the exact same port exposed and need to be reachable via the exact same port. Sounds weird and it is but well lets go with that so:

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
   "ipv6": true,
   "fixed-cidr-v6": "2a01:a:b:c:FFFF::/80"
}
```

Create a network for easier reference..

```
docker network create --ipv6 --subnet 2a01:a:b:c:AAAA::/80 --gateway 2a01:a:b:c:AAAA::1 --subnet 172.18.16.0/24 test
```

Now I got a `test` named network and can start containers on it:

```
/usr/bin/docker run -it --rm --net test --ip6 2a01:a:b:c:AAAA:1::2 -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx:latest
```

Now we have in netstat:

```
netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40945         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          31926551   17395/containerd    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        31917578   32693/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15061      816/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          31979291   23983/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          15063      816/sshd            
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        31917577   32693/systemd-resol
```

The problem is that it binds to ::::80 instead of the container IP. I can access nginx from the outside like this via ping6, curl on the configured ip as well as gateway ::1 of `test`(which I don't understand why) and also on the Ipv4 Address and IPv6 Address of `eth0`

What I want is that it answers to ping as well as on its own IP but not on the others. I need another nginx which also listens on `80`. I often read that all the ports in `EXPOSE` are reachable by default even if they are not bound to the host when IPv6 is enabled on the container. This seems not to be the case here. Binding with `-p [ipv6]:80:80` will result in errors.

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which doesn't have ports. Ports are transport addresses for some protocols (TCP and UDP). ICMP is an integral part of IP, so it simply uses the IP addressing. Also, while TCP and UDP use the same port numbers, the ports are _not_ the same. TCP port 12345 is _not_ UDP port 12345. Other transport protocols use other addressing or no addressing at all.

Comment: That much is clear to me. I had a setup where the ping did not even work, which is why I included it in the first place... It does not really matter. The point is the IP is reachable from the outside but it does not listen on any ports if I remove the port binding which should not be the case. It should still be there (at least thats what I read before) or there must be a way to make different containers listen on the same ports on different IPs - The hole purpose of IPv6 is to have application level IP resolution and endpoints.

Comment: "The hole [sic] purpose of IPv6 is to have application level IP resolution and endpoints." No, not really. The primary purpose of IPv6 is to restore the end-to-end IP paradigm where each host has a unique address, and devices in between do not maintain connection state. Application addresses are at the Transport layer (ports for TCP and UDP), not the Internet layer, because applications interface with transport protocols, that in turn use Internet protocols, that in turn use Data-Link protocols. On any one host, only one application can use a single port number for a given protocol.

Comment: I can still bind the same port to two different IPv4 addresses on the same host. Yes TCP and UDP are transport layer protocols but there can be more transportlink on a given host. It works with IPv4 and it does work in conjuction with docker. It does not work with IPv6 though with docker cause I cannot bind the containers port to a specific IP.